# How to Trigger an On-Demand Scheduled Query Using a Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

What I basically want to happen is my on demand scheduled query will run when a new file lands in my google cloud storage bucket. This query will load the CSV file into a temporary table, perform some transformation/cleaning and then append to a table.

Just to try and get the first part running, my on demand scheduled query looks like this. The idea being it will pick up the CSV file from the bucket and dump it into a table.

```
LOAD DATA INTO spreadsheep-20220603.Case_Studies.loading_test
from files
(
  format='CSV',
  uris=['gs://triggered_upload/*.csv']
);
```

I was in the process of setting up a Google Cloud Function that triggers when a file lands in the storage bucket, that seems to be fine but I haven't had luck working out how that function will trigger the scheduled query.

Any idea what bit of python code is needed in the function to trigger the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it's not really a scheduled query you want at all. You don't want one to run at regular intervals, you want to run a query in response to a certain event.

Now, you've rigged up a cloud function to execute some code whenever a new file is added to a bucket. What this cloud function needs is the BigQuery python client library. [Here's an example of how it's used](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/index.html?utm_source=googleapisdev&utm_medium=banner#perform-a-query).

All that remains is to wrap this code in an appropriate function and specify dependencies and permissions using the cloud functions python framework. [Here is a guide on how to do that](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-python#creating_a_function).